# Roll rate model building for a loan portfolio

Tags: securitization

I've a portfolio of a set of loans to analyse and I need to find the roll rate, Can someone explain the process of roll rate model building ? Thanks

Comment: One approach is to build a matrix showing the transitions between various states of credit quality for a loan, see for ex. http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1106/1106.4513.pdf (I am sure there are better references available, this is just 1 example).

Comment: Hi @noob2 I did read this but still couldn't know how do they get the number of loans that my default between 0-30months for example ? let's say I've 55000loans in my portfolio how can I get to the split from current to 0-30 to 30-60 ,,, till >180 months ? there where i struggle can you please explain how? I couldn't find a more explaintory document ....